# Squeeze Law and Signs

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)
$$
through the squeeze law. To do this, I have set up the inequality
$$
-1\le\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\le1
$$
Intuitively, I wrote down the next step, which would be
$$
-x\le x \cos \left(\frac2x\right)\le x
$$
and then taking the limits of all three. But I then realized that this inequality would not hold if $x$ was a negative number. How do I overcome this?

Comment: @quasi why did you multiply the middle term by $x$ and not by $\lvert x\rvert$?

Comment: ok, comment just disappeared.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$-\left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|\le x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\le \left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|$$

and

$$0\le \left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|\le |x|\to 0$$

then by squeeze theorem

$$\left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|\to 0 \implies x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\to 0$$

Comment: I understand how you got the second line, but could you clarify how you got the first line?

Comment: For any expression $f(x)$ we have that $$-|f(x)|\le f(x) \le |f(x)|$$

Comment: I can accept the first two lines to be true on their own, but I don't see how they work together to form the third line.. sorry, but could you explain?

Comment: For the second line by squeeze theorem, since $|x|\to 0$ also  $\left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|\to 0$ and for the first line  by squeeze theorem again since $\left|x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\right|\to 0$ also $x\cos \left(\frac2x\right)\to 0$.

Comment: okok, that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you :)))

Comment: @tim9800 You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute values to avoid having to consider cases.

$$0\leq |x\cos(2/x)-0|= |x||\cos(2/x)|\leq |x|$$

Comment: Is 
$$
\lvert x\rvert \lvert \cos\frac2x \rvert
$$
the same as 
$$
x \cos\frac2x ?
$$

Comment: @tim9800 One is the absolute value of the other. The thing is that if the absolute value tends to zero, so does the function.